# How can I count the values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have attempted to print all the values of my array, however I cannot seem to get the total count of the array. I've tried count(), sizeOf() and array_count_values but neither of these functions seems to do the job.

```
$query = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT orderStatus FROM customerOrders");                


foreach ($query->results() as $orderered) {

   $result_array = array($orderered);
 //print_r($result_array);

  $orderData = array_map(function ($object) { return $object->orderStatus; }, $result_array);

  $test = json_decode(json_encode($result_array), true);



  $ORvalue = serialize($test);


  $ORvalue2 = unserialize($ORvalue);


  $orderValueNEW = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $ORvalue2);


  print_r($orderValueNEW);//debug 


 }//close foreach loop
```

Results of the array after printing:

```
Array ( [orderStatus] => 0 ) 
Array ( [orderStatus] => 0 ) 
Array ( [orderStatus] => 0 ) 
Array ( [orderStatus] => 1 ) 
Array ( [orderStatus] => 1 )
```

After performing count() and sizeOf:

```
11111
```

After running array_count_values:

```
echo (array_count_values($orderValueNEW));
ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray
```

Comment: Are you trying to count the total number of results from the database?

Comment: Not the sum of all of them, but how many there are in the database.

Comment: `count($query->results());`

Comment: Not only is this question highly likely to be a duplicate, we don't know what your expected result is.  3 or 5? And why? I'm voting Unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count` function would certainly work here:

```php
$results = $query->results();

$num = count($values);

foreach($results as $ordered) { // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're probably running count($orderValueNew); which does contain one array each time, with a key of orderstatus. Whether or not the orderstatus has a value of 0 or 1 makes no difference.